# C# Memory Leak on on different machines

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, bitmap, garbage-collection

**Background info**

I've developed a desktop application with Windows Form (C#) for scanning, previewing and saving images.
The app behaviour while scanning is the following:

1. Scan *n* images
2. Get a Bitmap for each image and store it in a temporary file
3. Show resized thumbnails as a preview

---

**Image memory management: Compressible images**

For managing the memory usage, I've created a  CompressibleImage class which encapsulates a Bitmap file and reads/writes images file on a FileStream. When an image is not longer required by the application, it is written into a file stream. When the app requires an image (ie. user double-click on a thumbnail), a Bitmap file is created from the stream. Here are the main **CompressibleImage's** methods:

```
/// Gets the uncompressed image. If the image is compressed, it will be uncompressed
public Image GetDecompressedImage()
    {
        if (decompressedImage == null)
        {
            // Read Bitmap from file stream
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            decompressedImage = new Bitmap(stream);
        }
        return decompressedImage;
    }


/// Clears the uncompressed image, leaving the compressed one in memory.
public void ClearDecompressedImage()
{
    // If Bitmap file exists, write it to file and dispose it
    if (decompressedImage != null)
    {
        if (stream == null)
        {
            stream = new FileStream(FileStreamPath, FileMode.Create);    
        }
        decompressedImage.Save(stream, format);
        // The Dispose() call does not solve the issue
        // decompressedImage.Dispose();
        decompressedImage = null;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Class destructor. It disposes the decompressed image (if this exists), 
    /// closes the stream and delete the temporary file associated.
    /// </summary>
    ~CompressibleImage()
    {
        if (decompressedImage != null)
        {
            decompressedImage.Dispose();
        }
        if(stream != null)
        {
            stream.Close();
            File.Delete(stream.Name);
            stream.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

---

**Application level**

The application uses CompressibleImage to create image files mainly during the scan method and the saving process.
The scan method works fine and it basically:

1. Acquire Bitmap from scanner
2. Create a CompressibleImage from the scanned Bitmap
3. Write the Bitmap to the file stream

The save method works fine on my machine and its behaviour is as follows:
 1. For each CompressibleImage decompress (read & build) Bitmap from stream
 2. Save image
 3. Compress image

Here is the **save** method:

```
private void saveImage_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(OutputPath) ==  false && File.Exists(OutputPath) == false)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(OutputPath);
        }

        ListView.CheckedListViewItemCollection checkedItems = listView1.CheckedItems;
        if(checkedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < checkedItems.Count; ++i)
            {
                int index = checkedItems[i].Index;
                Bitmap image = (Bitmap)compressibleImageList.ElementAt(index).GetDecompressedImage();
                try
                {
                    image.Save(OutputPath + index.ToString() +
                               Module.PNG_FORMAT, ImageFormat.Png);
                    compressibleImageList.ElementAt(index).ClearDecompressedImage();
                    progressForm.Increment();
                    image = null;
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Issue Description**

In my machine the application works fine. There is no memory leak and the **scan** and **save** methods do their job smoothly and with a reasonable memory usage (scanning 100 papersheets with less than < 140MB pick).

The problem is, when I tried to test the application on other machines, the Garbage collector doesn't free up the memory, causing a **MemoryException** during the execution of both methods and when the amount of image is reasonably high (>40). The exception is thrown inside the **CompressibleImage.GetDecompressedImage()** method when I attempt to decompress (read) an image:

```
decompressedImage = new Bitmap(stream);
```

Although I known that the GC clean the memory randomly, in this case it seems like it doesn't even run and in fact the memory is released only when I close the application.

It is possible such different behaviour on similar machines?

**System's info**

Here are some info about the testing environments. Both machines have:

- Processor: Intel i7 2.30GHz
- RAM: 8GB
- Type: 64-bit
- OS: Windows 7 Pro SP 1

Comment: Not saying that this is the problem, but your destructor implementation is not right.  You shouldn't reference other managed objects in there, as there is no guarantee that they are still accessible.  Look into implementing the `IDisposable` interface instead. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure about you MemoryException, please provide full stacktrace.

However, I can see you are doing an obvious mistake in your destructor. 
You SHOULD NOT refer your managed resources in the Destructor. The reason is being that, GC and Finalizer are using heuristic algorithms to trigger them and you can never predict the execution order of finalizers for your managed objects.

That's why you should use 'disposing' flag in your dispose method and avoid touching managed objects when the execution is coming from the finalizer.

Below example show the general best practice to implement IDisposable interface. Reference : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public class DisposeExample
{
    // A base class that implements IDisposable. 
    // By implementing IDisposable, you are announcing that 
    // instances of this type allocate scarce resources. 
    public class MyResource: IDisposable
    {
        // Pointer to an external unmanaged resource. 
        private IntPtr handle;
        // Other managed resource this class uses. 
        private Component component = new Component();
        // Track whether Dispose has been called. 
        private bool disposed = false;

        // The class constructor. 
        public MyResource(IntPtr handle)
        {
            this.handle = handle;
        }

        // Implement IDisposable. 
        // Do not make this method virtual. 
        // A derived class should not be able to override this method. 
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            // This object will be cleaned up by the Dispose method. 
            // Therefore, you should call GC.SupressFinalize to 
            // take this object off the finalization queue 
            // and prevent finalization code for this object 
            // from executing a second time.
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        // Dispose(bool disposing) executes in two distinct scenarios. 
        // If disposing equals true, the method has been called directly 
        // or indirectly by a user's code. Managed and unmanaged resources 
        // can be disposed. 
        // If disposing equals false, the method has been called by the 
        // runtime from inside the finalizer and you should not reference 
        // other objects. Only unmanaged resources can be disposed. 
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            // Check to see if Dispose has already been called. 
            if(!this.disposed)
            {
                // If disposing equals true, dispose all managed 
                // and unmanaged resources. 
                if(disposing)
                {
                    // Dispose managed resources.
                    component.Dispose();
                }

                // Call the appropriate methods to clean up 
                // unmanaged resources here. 
                // If disposing is false, 
                // only the following code is executed.
                CloseHandle(handle);
                handle = IntPtr.Zero;

                // Note disposing has been done.
                disposed = true;

            }
        }

        // Use interop to call the method necessary 
        // to clean up the unmanaged resource.
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Kernel32")]
        private extern static Boolean CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

        // Use C# destructor syntax for finalization code. 
        // This destructor will run only if the Dispose method 
        // does not get called. 
        // It gives your base class the opportunity to finalize. 
        // Do not provide destructors in types derived from this class.
        ~MyResource()
        {
            // Do not re-create Dispose clean-up code here. 
            // Calling Dispose(false) is optimal in terms of 
            // readability and maintainability.
            Dispose(false);
        }
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Insert code here to create 
        // and use the MyResource object.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I come from the C++ and I've just started to deal with managed/unmanaged resources. This solution has effectively improved the memory usage. I'm still running some more tests to ensure this work on all the test machines. By the way I'm still a little bit confused about why in the previous solution I had such different behaviours. Have you ever experienced such issues?

Comment: @Nickeat : I guess, that's because of referencing managed objects in the destructor. May be release and debug build has some effect.. Not quite sure.

Answer (score -1):

When opening files or streams using a class that incorporates the `IDisposable` interface one should usually make use of `using`. This will ensure that after the `using` statement the `Dispose` method is called. If implemented correctly, this will ensure that the unmanaged resources are released.

[MSDN Article on 'using' statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, but this explanation is just weird. I agree that OP should be using the `IDisposable` pattern, which enables the use of `using`. But `using` doesn't trigger the GC as you seem to be implying. Also, I assume you mean destructor. But, about the destructor, if implemented properly, the `IDisposable` pattern should prevent the invocation of the `destructor`, not the other way around.

Comment: Answer edited, you're correct, I did mix up a few facts.